# Jenkins Git userContent plugin

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I recently tried to install the [Git userContent plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+userContent+plugin) on Jenkins 1.546. After restarting Jenkins the following error occured:

```
hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException: java.lang.Error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:234)
Caused by: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException: java.lang.Error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:269)
    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:44)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:908)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:807)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:82)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:78)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:222)
Caused by: java.lang.Error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:109)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder$TaskImpl.run(TaskMethodFinder.java:169)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:282)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$7.runTask(Jenkins.java:897)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:210)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:105)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.onLoaded(GitSCM.java:1389)
    ... 13 more
```

I tried reverting to Jenkins 1.544 via the **jenkins.war.bak**, but the error persists. I can not access Jenkins anymore. Is there any way to recover from this, or at least a decent way to re-install Jenkins without losing any data?

Comment: **Solved**: Deleted plugins\git-userContent.jpi from Jenkins installation directory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my case it was because I had selected the git-client.jpi and git-server.jpi files for installation, but before they could be downloaded by Jenkins plugin manager, the download got stuck at a database plugin download. I restarted Jenkins and I think Jenkins mistook the not-yet-downloaded git plugin as already downloaded.

To solve the problem, just navigate to `/var/lib/jenkins/plugins` and delete the jpi files that are causing the problem. The restart Jenkins and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 5):

The same issue occurred to me while i was disabling the plugin from Jenkins.

To Remove this error i have removed the partially disabled plugin which in my case was  `credentials.jpi.disabled`

Traverse to `/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/`

Find the disabled file , which in my case was `credentials.jpi.disabled` and removing this file from the plugin directory.

Restart Jenkins service

service jenkins restart

and it worked !!